# How to view Jira Issues in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, jira

I have added company Jira Site to VS code. I am able to open issues using Jira Number. But I want to see all the Jira Issues using JQL. How do I view all the Jira Issues.

Answer (score 0):

#### Official Plugin from Atlassian

When using the plugin from Visual Studio Marketplace: [Jira and Bitbucket (Atlassian Labs)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atlassian.atlascode&ssr=false#qna), you can use the JIRA *issues explorer*:

> Jira Software issues in VS Code
>
> The Jira issue explorer displays all open issues, or you can customize the query using JQL.

See also:

- [Jira Software and Bitbucket in VS Code - Work Life by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jira-software-and-bitbucket-in-vs-code)
- [atlassianlabs / atlascode / issues / #692 - Imported filter and custom JQL return no results but show results in Jira — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlascode/issues/692/imported-filter-and-custom-jql-return-no)

#### Other plugins

Or you can use the plugin [Jira Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=crhistianr.jira-issues):

> Custom filtering
>
> By default you will see issues assigned to you that have not yet been resolved but you can provide your own JQL (Jira Query Language) expression to filter issues exactly the way you want.
>
> `jira.jqlExpression`